# Applications manifest file causing problems on Win 7 environment

Tags: c#, .net, manifest

My app has been upgraded along the way from .net 1.1 to 3.5. On win 7 64 bit environment I have o manually remove the app.exe.manifest file as otherwise it crashes when it launches.

I use a visual studio deploy & setup project to install. In the exe's application settings itself i've tried all the options in the dropdown relating to what manifest file to use including using none (manifest still gets created).

Ideally i'd like the office look and feel but worst case scenario having it work full stop is fine now, with or without.

Any help appreciated.

Update: Manifsest file

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
    version="6.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
    language="*"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

So, for a 64 bit environment, this clearly isn't going to work, but I add that this is the manifest that is created when i set 'Create application without a manifest' in my application settings.

Comment: How would you know what manifest is embedded when you say "create without a manifest" - have you looked inside the exe with mt.exe? The mere presence of a file called app.manifest in your project does not mean one is being embedded in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Are you using any native libraries? I mean non managed (.NET) ones?

b) Do you have problems with Win7 32-bit platforms? Or only 64-bit platforms?

c) Screenshot of the actual error would be very helpful here.

d) If you are using multiple DLLs in your exe, then information about those would be great help in debugging.

Here is a stab with limited information...

I had a similar problem once, and that was because one of the libraries was 32-bit while the target platform for the exe was "any" i.e. on 64-bit platform the .NET app loaded up as 64-bit and caused problems when the execution flow reached the point where the 32-bit library was loaded.

I hope this helps.