# .net 2.0 windows app requires elevated uac permissions

Tags: .net, uac, windows

On windows 7 my windows app won't run unless I elevate its permissions by setting it to 'run as administrator'. Is there anyway I can set this in the installer project or on the windows app itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, including an application manifest you can do it:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel
level="requireAdministrator"
uiAccess="true"/>
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345843/applications-manifest-file-causing-problems-on-win-7-environment [A thread I created a while back - I ended up having to create the app without a manifest to get it to run on win 7 64 bit]

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a manifest file for your .NET application](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/7987/making-a-net-app-run-on-vista-with-administrator-priviledges/) which indicates that it requires administrator rights when it runs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345843/applications-manifest-file-causing-problems-on-win-7-environment [A thread I created a while back - I ended up having to create the app without a manifest to get it to run on win 7 64 bit]